# Unexplainable 404 error in Flask

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, routes

I started going through  [Miguel Grinberg's Flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)  and everything was going great until I started encountering unexplainable HTTP 404 errors.

After the first part of the tutorial, my project directory tree looked something like...

```
\project
    \app
        init.py
        views.py
    \tmp
    \flask
        <flask environment files>
    run.py
```

The contents of my `run.py` file are as follows.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

My `__init__.py` file looks like this...

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

`views.py` file goes...

```
from app import app
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

All the contents are in accordance with the tutorial but when i execute the `run.py` file and type localhost:5000/index in my browser, i get an HTTP 404 error saying that the server isn't able to find the URL. However, when I type localhost:5000 I see the desired output. To state this more clearly, I'm getting the expected routing only for the root URL and no other.
I have executed this code locally only.

Any leads on explaining this anomaly would be greatly appreciated.

PS: As instructed in the tutorial, I am using virtualenv. Virtualenv and flask packages, both are of the latest version in my machine and were downloaded using pip.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me on Ubuntu, with both python2.7 and python3.5 virtualenvs.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to access `/index/` instead of `/index`? Does it work if you remove one of the routes?

Comment: If I were you, I would commit my effort on github.com so that all can easily see what's going on thoroughly